# click on button then render a component in livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire

I just added a button in a page, when I click on this button, I must see another page which we can create channel, group and a conversation on this page. The page I was talking about is a component.

- How  can I do this with `@click in livewire`?

This is my code for my button:

```
<div x-data="{ newMassage: false }" >
<button @click="newMassage=true" type="button"
class="fixed bottom-16 right-2 z-50 inline-flex items-center justify-center w-12 h-12 shadow-md font-medium bg-secondary-600 rounded-full hover:bg-secondary-700 group focus:ring-4 focus:ring-secondary-300 focus:outline-none dark:focus:ring-secondary-800">
```

My component that is not completed:

```
<div class="pt-16 max-w-md mx-auto"  :class="newMassage? '' : ''">
</div>
```